# TSQL - Do you calculate values then sum, or sum first then calculate values?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sum

I feel stupid asking this - there is probably a math rule I am forgetting.

I am trying to calculate a gross profit based on net sales, cost, and billbacks.

I get two different values based on how I do the calculation:

```
(sum(netsales) - sum(cost)) + sum(billbackdollars) as CalculateOutsideSum,
sum((netsales - cost) + BillBackDollars) as CalculateWithinSum
```

This is coming off of a basic transaction fact table.

In this particular example, there are about 90 records being summed, and I get the following results

```
CalculateOutsideSum: 234.77
CalculateWithinSum:  247.70
```

I imagined this would be some sort of transitive property and both results would be the same considering it's just summation.

Which method is correct?

Comment: both methods should give the same results, something has gone wrong somewhere - rounding problem, data changed, selection method changed - but the mathematical reasoning is correct that they are equal

Answer (score 1):

From a mathematical point of view, you should get exactly the same value with both your formulas.

Anyway in this cases it's better to performs sum after any calculation.

**EDIT AFTER OPENER RESPONSE:**

And treat your data with **isnull** function or other casting function which increases data precision.

Rounding, formatting and castings which decreases data precision should be applied after sums.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out...

Problem was Net Sales was null for 3 rows, causing the calculation to become null, and incorrectly summing. After adding an isnull, both sums come out the same.